# Run code when MacBook lid is closed with external monitor connected

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion

I want to get a notification for when my MacBook's lid is closed, when an external monitor is connected.

Lion prevents the computer from sleeping when an external monitor is plugged in, so I can't listen for sleep notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Quartz Display Services to watch for changes to the display configuration.  See [`CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback).